# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() php warning

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam newbie to php and codeigniter.

I have error in php,

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/search.php

Line Number: 44
```

Line 44 is: foreach ( $data as $key => $value )

There is some syntax error here,
inside this if statement, if (!empty($user['search'])), $data is printed correctly,whereas in this if statement,if(!empty($data)), $data is not printed. Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` means that `$data` is not an array, but does not mean is empty.

Comment: try changing $data = json_decode($user['search'])->result; to $data = json_decode($user['search']->result); and see if it works

Comment: if i do this, it gives an error as,
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/search.php

Line Number: 41

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have any value inside your looping variable( `$data` ).

You can print their values for check whether the variable contains values.

Comment: An empty array wouldn't throw that error. It just doesn't get inside of the loop, that's all.

Comment: I also think it's better to do so, but it's not mandatory, and it's not the problem here. That's it.

Comment: Which means you can print $data array

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
$data = json_decode($user['search'])->result;
```

By :

```
$data = json_decode($user['search'], true);
```

`json_decode` works that way :

```
var_dump(json_decode($json)); // returns object(stdClass)
var_dump(json_decode($json, true)); returns array
```

Your $data was an object, while foreach strictly wants an array.